# Fluentd and skype for business

Tags: command-line, fluentd, skype-for-business

Is there any way that you can use Skype for Business with Fluentd?

If there's no such plugin, can I send a message to a Skype for Business recipient using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Skype for Business (=SfB) has an XMPP Gateway mostly out of the box in the product (if the admin configured it correctly) as written [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn933894.aspx):

> Edge Servers also include a fully-integrated Extensible Messaging and
>   Presence Protocol (XMPP) proxy, with an XMPP gateway included on Front
>   End Servers. You can configure these XMPP components to enable your
>   Skype for Business Server users to add contacts from XMPP-based
>   partners for instant messaging and presence.

you could setup an XMPP Server (e.g. Jabber) and then build a federation between the XMPP Server and the Skype for Business environment. Its quite easy to do that.

For the XMPP Server there exist a LOT of possible options to send messages via a command line for example [sendxmpp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sendxmpp.1p.html):

```
echo "hello bob!" | sendxmpp -s hello someone@jabber.org
```

Then you are free from anything which relay to an Microsoft API and can use all the XMPP plugins / libraries. The [XMPP gateway solution outlined above will also work with Lync 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721881(v=ocs.15).aspx) if you need that.

If that federation is in place you can also use this [Fluentd](https://github.com/fluent) plugin: [fluent-plugin-jabber](https://github.com/todesking/fluent-plugin-jabber) to send messages via the XMPP federation.

P.S:
You can also connect the network monitoring solution Nagios to an XMPP Server so that Nagios send warning messages to the Skype for Business users via that way. If you need to search for other implementation examples.